# How to calculate weighted average of averages in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have product review data. The reviews are out of 5 stars and I know how many there are (ie quantity of reviews). I'm trying to calculate a weighted average of the reviews because I'm trying to distinguish the reviews by different product categories. If I simply do a pivot table average, it doesn't take into account the number of reviews. This is wrong:

[image]

So far, I have read and tried a lot with sumproduct and average.weighted but these seem to be better at calculating weighted averaged when you have the actual original values themselves (vs. the averages + quantity).

How does one calculate weighted average of averages:

[image]

Demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WIdoCjazfprxRN5XW5PJ8lBQNAf8qmjgmRaZd3lhyJE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kyle, it looks like you want this:

cat 1: `AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(B2:B6, C2:C6)`

cat 2: `AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(B7:B11, C7:C11)`

cat 3: `AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(B12:B17, C12:C17)`

cat 4: `AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(B18:B22, C18:C22)`

If you don't always know how many listings there will be for each category:

Set up a small table of two columns with headers, say "CAT | Weighted AVG"

List your categories by exact name from row 2 downward in the first column (in my suggested examples, the "CAT" column):

In row 2 of the "Weighted AVG" column beside that, place this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(IF(A2:A=E2,B2:B),IF(A2:A=E2,C2:C)))`

Then copy it down so that a version resides next to each of the categories you've listed under "CAT."